# Basic Javascript issue (adding value)

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/JWww3/

I'm not sure to understand why this code is not working.

What I want to add +1 to the "ajout" variable when I click on the "+1" button.
And if ajout = 5 (after 5 clicks)...then alert("Hello");

Why am I doing wrong?

Here's my code :

HTML :

```
<input type="button" onclick="clickit();" id="click1" value="+1"/>​
```

JS :

```
var ajout = 0;
function clickit()
{
 ajout +=1;    
}

if (ajout==5)
{
alert("TEST");   
}
```

​

Thank you!

Comment: What happens? What's the code that doesn't look work like? Please try to post details here as *well* as having a fiddle :)

Comment: You are doing everything wrong, learn some JS basics.

Comment: Can you add the code in question here so the question gets perserved for future generations to look to for inspiration? (links go bad over time)

Comment: The code has been added. Why am I getting a -1? Can't a beginner ask questions here? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var ajout = 0;
function clickit()
{
    ajout += 1;

    if (ajout==5)
    {
        alert("TEST");   
    }   
}
```

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer, `if` condition was never executing on click event since it was outside of function which is triggered on click.

Comment: Thank you, it's working. I studied the way you made it work and I understand it now. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it should be

```
ajout += 1;
```

And what you have is

```
=+
```

Comment: No that's not the issue you can use either

Answer (score 1):

Select "no wrap (body)" option from jsfiddle. Otherwise `clickit` function is defined only after DOM has loaded, which means it could never get executed.

Also make sure to put that `alert` inside `clickit` function to make sure it gets executed when you call that function.

Comment: The alert call is not placed inside `clickit`, but is instead executed when the script is loaded. Move it inside `clickit` and it will be executed!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var ajout = 0;
jQuery('#click1').click(function(){
    ajout += 1;    
    console.log(ajout);
    if (ajout==5)
    {
    alert("TEST");   
    }
});
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JWww3/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<input type="button" onclick="clickit();" id="click1" value="+1"/>
<script>
var ajout = 0;
function clickit()
{
 ajout += 1;    
    if (ajout==5)
    {
        alert("TEST");   
    }
}

</script>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other 2 have said, your evaluation code should be within the function, otherwise it is NOT going to be called every time the button is clicked, which I think is what you are after.

```
var ajout = 0;
function clickit()
{
 ajout++;  
 if (ajout==5)
   alert("TEST");   
}
```